# Can't access elements of an array using request limiter for API requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

First of all, thanks for your time here.

I am using node.js to make API calls programmatically. I have an array filled with numbers and I would like to loop over it to send API requests to check if the number is valid. The problem is that I need to manage the throughput of my API requests to avoid an HTTP 429 (due to the API provider restrictions). I am also keeping the HTTP connection alive to speed up the requests rate.

I am using an external request limiter https://www.npmjs.com/package/limiter.

For simplicity, I will include numbercheck as a dependency, which doesn't exist but it's to avoid getting things more complicated.

My code is the following:

```
    var RateLimiter = require('limiter').RateLimiter;
    var http = require('http');
    var Checknumber = require('numbercheck')
    var agent = new http.Agent({
    keepAlive: true,
    maxSockets: 1,
    keepAliveMsecs: 3000
    })

//final is the array containing 100 phone numbers
var final = [xxxxxxxx, xxxxx, .......,];




//This limit the API requests to 1 per second
 var limiter = new RateLimiter(1, 'second');


for  (x=0; x<final.length; x++){

   limiter.removeTokens(1, function() {

    console.log(final[x], x);
//This console.log is to debug  

Checknumber.get({ number: final[x]}, (error, response) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error)
      }  
      else {
        console.log(response)

      }

    }
)}
)}
```

The result that I get is that `final[x] is undefined` and therefore the API requests fail

`console.log(final[x], x)`  returns : `undefined 100`

It seems that somehow, I can't access `final[x]` by index.

Could you please help here?

Regards

I've also tried to pass `final[x]` in `limiter.removeTokens(1, function(final[x]) {...`
but I get

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the variable assignment in the for loop:
`(var x = 0; x < final.length; x++)`

Other things I've noticed:

1. It's down to your coding style and preference but most of the time when looping I prefer using iterator's such as .forEach() or .map(), as it makes the code much more declarative. In this instance .forEach would be the correct iterator to use.
2. I find it easier to debug code if it is consistent, consider sticking to an ECMAScript Versions Syntax, so if you are going to commit to ES6 (You're using arrow functions), then use that throughout. Also consider using const and let over using var.

   ```
   final.forEach((item, index) => {
     limiter.removeTokens(1, () => {
        console.log(item, index);
        Checknumber.get({ number: item}, (error, response) => {
          if (error) {
            console.error(error)
          } else {
            console.log(response)
          }
        })
      })
    }
   ```

Comment: Amazing. Good catch @wntwrk. It works fine now and good advice as well regarding forEach. I guess that I'm thinking the old way with traditional for loops. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problems, something else I should have added was to consider using a linter within your project, I use eslint. It helps highlight syntax errors like the above and will general save you time in debugging issues.